# Array of objects with blank key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with `date keys` like this:

```
{
  "2018-05-02": [
    { id: 1,
      name: "Bob"
    },
    { id: 2,
      name: "Martin"
    }
  ],
  "2018-06-21": [
    { id: 35,
      name: "Joseph"
    },
    { id: 39,
      name: "Gary"
    }
  ]
};
```

and I need to have the following structure of this array:

```
[
  [
    { id: 1,
      name: "Bob"
    },
    { id: 2,
      name: "Martin"
    }
  ],
  [
    { id: 35,
      name: "Joseph"
    },
    { id: 39,
      name: "Gary"
    }
  ]
];
```

How can I remove these "date keys" and get desired array?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure, thats the right structure? Seems like you have an array but then using object keys. Shouldn't it be array of objects?

Comment: Agree with @CertainPerformance, there is no attempt to solve the question. But just in case if you are stuck, try this `Object.keys(t).map(key => t[key])` where t is the original array of objects.

Comment: @JeremyRajan The desired array must have a list of grouped elements, so, I need elements grouped, put them inside an array that matches with desired sort and then put this array inside another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Js, object use `{}`, not `[]`

You can try this code:

```
var days = {
    "2018-05-02": [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Bob"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Martin"
    }],
    "2018-06-21": [{
        id: 35,
        name: "Joseph"
    }, {
        id: 39,
        name: "Gary"
    }]
};
var data = [];

for (var key in days) {
    data.push(days[key])
}

console.log(data);
// [[{
//     "id": 1,
//     "name": "Bob"
// }, {
//     "id": 2,
//     "name": "Martin"
// }], [{
//     "id": 35,
//     "name": "Joseph"
// }, {
//     "id": 39,
//     "name": "Gary"
// }]]
```

Comment: I used your solution to solve the problem, just stored "date keys" at a new array and stored this array with spread operator inside object before loop and push to data array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can't remove that key.for map, key cant be empty or null. you may do one thing while constructing the array itself (from Java or PHP or some other) you can change. For example, First, create the map and insert the data whatever you want. Then insert them into the list and again insert them into another list.  

    List l2=new List();
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        List l1=new List();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Map m1=new HashMap();
            m1.put("id",1);
            m1.put("name","bob");
           l1.add(m1);
        }
       l2.add(l1);
    }

Here, l2 contains your required structure of data
.Now, you can get them in javascript easily.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, This code is invalid by the way. This is the valid version:

```js
var log = {
  "2018-05-02": [
    { "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    { "id": 2,
      "name": "Martin"
    }
  ],
  "2018-06-21": [
    { "id": 35,
      "name": "Joseph"
    },
    { "id": 39,
      "name": "Gary"
    }
  ]
};
```

Second, as Jeremy Rajan said in the comments, use the `Object.keys(t).map(key => t[key])` method as follows (use it with the code above):

```js
var newObj = Object.keys(log).map(key => log[key]);
console.log(newObj);
```

Third, try to put some effort into trying and fixing the issue on your own or searching for a solution before posting a question here.

Hope this helps.